# How do I make a BOOL variable that is randomly either YES or NO?

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I want to have a BOOL variable that randomly holds either a yes or no. Can someone please tell me how to write this in Objective-C?

Comment: So what have you tried? There are probably a number of ways to do this (e.g. if random number is even or odd).

Answer (score 2):

One way is using the following code:

```
 BOOL a = arc4random_uniform(2) == 1;
```